# Two $3\times 3$ matrices with different similarity of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Give an example of two $3 \times 3$ matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PQ$ and $QP$ are not similar and neither of them, I mean $PQ$ and $QP$, is equal to 0.

Note: As $PQ$ and $QP$ have the same eigenvalues, we cannot work on their e-values to find such an example.

Comment: Are $P$ and $Q$ singular or non-singular?

Comment: @TedShifrin Not necessarily. They can be anything, but $PQ$ and $QP$ are not zero.

Comment: My question was meant to be a hint to you. Think more.

Comment: @TedShifrin Good point. I found them. Thanks. So, singular!

Comment: Good job. If either one is non-singular, then the product matrices must be similar. You can prove that in a jiffy.

Comment: Yes. That is the definition of similarity!

Comment: Why don't you post an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that neither $P$ nor $Q$ is nonsingular, or else $PQ$ will be similar to $QP$.

Also, neither $P$ nor $Q$ is rank-one. Note that a rank-one matrix $xy^T$ is diagonalisable if and only if its trace is nonzero. If it is diagonalisable, it is similar to $\operatorname{diag}(y^Tx,0,\ldots,0)$; if it is non-diagonalisable, it is nilpotent. Now, if $P=uv^T$, then $PQ=uv^TQ$ and $QP=Quv^T$ have the same trace. Hence they are either both similar to $\operatorname{diag}(v^TQu,0,0)$ or both similar to the rank-one nilpotent Jordan block.

It follows that both $P$ and $Q$ are of rank two. To make $PQ$ and $QP$ dissimilar, it suffices for them to have different ranks. Since their ranks are at most two and they are required to be nonzero, we want one of them to have rank one and the other rank two. Here is an example that works over any field:
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&0},
\ Q=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0},
\ PQ=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0},
\ QP=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0}.
$$